# How to solve this mathematical problem using the trigonometric method?

Tags: calculus, integration, trigonometry, trigonometric-integrals

I am a high school student that is doing Newton’s law of cooling for his school report. I passed by a website that is finding the general formula [T(t)] with an approximation of the environmental temperature. Everything was mostly understandable but at one point, the person used Mathcad to solve the integrals. I am therefore interested on how this mathematical process can be carried out analytically so please if you have any idea of how to solve it analytically let me know.

Website: http://calculus7.com/sitebuildercontent/sitebuilderfiles/nwtnslawcling1.pdf

Equation I have(assuming k = 0.128):[image]

The way I would like it to be:

[image]

note: the graph I trying to get is for cooling and the website is using heating instead of cooling.
Note 2: on my equation, T(t) is supposed to be the same thing as y(t) in the equation from the website.

Comment: I think both integrals should have closed (analytic) form

Comment: Is your problem very similar to Example 2?

Comment: Yes that’s it..

Comment: In that case, please post $T(t)$, initial temperature $y(0)$ and $k$

Comment: I don’t quiet understand what you mean?

Comment: It looks like the expressions you posted are not quite correct. If you post the three inputs mentioned earlier, it will be easier to solve the problem.

Comment: Oh I realized thanks a lot for letting me know.

Comment: No answer??????

Comment: Are you sure about the factor $e^{0.269}$? Should it be $e^{0.269t}$ instead?

Comment: Sorry again I had a writing error I will change it.

Comment: Do you know how to solve it by the way?

Comment: Probably I do...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/116894/discussion-between-ptds-and-general-mo7).